# How to open a website using eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse

I've designed a website using dreamviewer. How can I open this as a project in eclipse.?

Please help me.
Thank you!

Comment: not like that! I want to open the designed interface as a web applicatioN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I know what you mean, you want to import a dreamweaver project into Eclipse as a project (tell me if I'm wrong), presumably to do some editing.

Eclipse uses project files (.project) to define its projects. Dreamweaver doesn't make these, so you'll need to make a new project in eclipse. 
After you've done that, in the open project view on the left in eclipse, delete all the stuff it generated inside your new project (probably Java stuff which you don't care about). Then go File > Import > Files from Filesystem, and select all the files from your website. Make sure that they ate linked, not copied (if I remember correctly there is a checkbox), otherwise your original website files won't change, only the eclipse ones. Then you should be able to edit your files.

Answer (score 1):

File | Import | File System -> find the html file(s) you want to open, select a folder to import it into, click finish.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new view - web browser.  `Window -> Show view - > Other` ( alt + shift + q, q) and choose Internal Web Browser.